# How to open Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 Nautilus (File Manager) preferences?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, nautilus

How do you get to the preferences in Nautilus / Files?

Running 16.04.03 with Gnome Flashback Metacity.

In the Unity interface I don't even get the triple horizontal bar (upper right) icon for the "location" menu. I do with Gnome.

Using 'dconf' didn't change the settings I wanted to change, e.g. default to list, not grid.

As long as were at it how do you activate the resize areas on the corners?

Does Nautilus actually work properly for anyone?

I have read all the older versions of this question so it is not a duplicate. Also, I know this is going to upset some, lets have an answer on how to fix this or an explanation of why it is broken. Please don't provide alternate answers like in the previous questions. Most of them I have tried and didn't help anyway, as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known [bug 1518786](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1518786) (reported on 2015-11-22).

IMHO Nautilus [is dead](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/files-nautilus-v3-28-will-lose-the-desktop-icons-capability/3115/28?u=norbert).

MATE DE will be the last resort with its fully-functional and powerful Caja.

Comment: Compliments on that response given the other similar questions about this problem.